# How do you calculate a large power modulo a small number?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, exponentiation

How do I calculate $12345^{12345} \operatorname{mod} 17$? I cant do it on a calculator? How would I show this systematically?

Comment: Hint: $a^b\bmod n = (a\bmod n)^b\bmod n$. [Fermat's Little Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) can be very useful too!

Comment: Thanks I worked it out but say if x ≡ 12345^12345 mod 17 how would I work out x?

Comment: You've been given all you need, time to show some effort.

Answer (score 4):

Hint: By Fermat's little theorem, if $c$ is a prime number, and $c$ don't divide $a$, $a^{c-1}\equiv 1 \mod c$

Comment: Thanks I worked it out but say if x ≡ 12345^12345 mod 17 how would I work out x?

Comment: @Isaac the question is answered see the other answers

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: $$12345=17\cdot726+3=3\pmod{17}$$ Now, show/observe that $3^{16}=1\pmod{17},$ so since $12345=771\cdot16+9,$ then what can we conclude about $3^{12345},$ *modulo* $17$?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is without using Fermat Little theorem(in case anyone does not know)

$12345\hspace{1 mm} mod \hspace{1 mm}17$=3

So question simplifies to
$3^ {12345}\hspace{1 mm} mod \hspace{1 mm}17$

$3^6\hspace{1 mm} mod \hspace{1 mm}17$=-2

So question simplifies to
$-2^ {2057}*-2^3\hspace{1 mm} mod \hspace{1 mm}17$

$-2^4\hspace{1 mm} mod \hspace{1 mm}17$=-1

So question simplifies to
$-1^ {514}*-2^3*-2\hspace{1 mm} mod \hspace{1 mm}17$=-1